# Probleme with strict_types - PHP

Tags: php

I set return type to int and i put 5.2 and 4.8 that the value will be 10 and its 'int' but why it returns fatal error?

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);
function jmp(float $n1,float $n2) : int {
return $n1 + $n2;
}
echo jmp(5.2,4.8);
?>
```

Comment: also, you're adding two floats, you don't ever convert the data type to an int.

Comment: Just change to `return (int) ($n1 + $n2);` as you would do in any other typesafe language.